# How to pass a C# list as a method parameter to objective C in Unity?

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I need to call a function defined in my `Objective-C` plugin from unity `c#` and pass a string array as a parameter.

Here is my C# method:

```
   public void StartRecording()
   {
            string[] keywords = { "sit", "stand", "eat"};
#if UNITY_EDITOR
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        _TAG_initKeywords(keywords, keywords.Length);
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
       
#endif
    }


#if UNITY_IPHONE
        [DllImport("__Internal")]
        private static extern void _TAG_initKeywords(string[] keywords, int count);
#endif
```

And the code in `Objective-C` which I tried to use is

```
    void _TAG_initKeywords(const char ** _keyword, int count){
        [vc initKeywords:_keyword WithCount:count];
    }


- (void) initKeywords:(const char**)_keywords WithCount: (int) keywordsCount {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < keywordsCount; i++) {
        NSString* keyword = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:_keywords[i]];
        if ([keywords containsObject:keyword]) {
            [keywords addObject:keyword];
        }
    }
}
```

However it seems `char**` is not the proper type to get the `string[]` data from `C#`.

How can I get this data properly?

I would also like to mention that using `const char *` as parameter type for `string` works fine.
My problem is with `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the proper way to pass the string array
Here is the code for `Objective-C`

```
 void _TAG_initKeywords(const char * _keywords[], int count)
{
        [vc initKeywords:_keywords WithCount:count];
}

- (void) initKeywords:(const char*[])_keywords WithCount: (int) keywordsCount 
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < keywordsCount; i++) {
        NSString* keyword = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:_keywords[i]];
        NSLog(@"%@",keyword);
        if (![keywords containsObject:keyword]) {
            [keywords addObject:keyword];
        }
    }

}
```